# VSCode editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations setting doesn't apply

Tags: visual-studio-code

No matter what I've tried, nothing is being applied to the color customizations.  What am I missing?  This really shouldn't be as complicated as it is.

The below snippet is just the latest attempt.  I've tried 20 other variations of this, along with various themes, not specifying a theme, this ridiculous `enabled` property in both scopes or not.  I've tried different rule properties, based on the Textmate scopes, ones that aren't defined, others that are.

I've restarted VSCode maybe 50x through this process as well.

These settings are being applied on the user `settings.json`.  There is no other matching definition in the workspace, or the same user settings file.

```json
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true,
    "[Tomorrow Night]": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
            "storage.type.class.php": {
                "foreground": "#333333"
            }
        }
    }
},
```